# How to send text file to bluetooth device with out user permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect to blue tooth device pragmatically with out user permission and send text File to other device. I know already how to connect and send connection request to other device but i want to connect to blue tooth device with out user permission. I am using this code to send text file but not working it says "CONNECTION PROBLEM"

```
public void sendFile(){
    String className = null;
    String packageName = null;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testfile.txt");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file) );

    PackageManager pm =this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities( intent, 0);

    if(appsList.size() > 0 ){
        boolean found = false;

        for(ResolveInfo info: appsList){
            packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
            if( packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")){
                className = info.activityInfo.name;
                found = true;
                break;// found
            }
        }
    }
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data through `Intent` requires user permission, you'll have to set up your own Bluetooth app.

Check out the sample https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html to learn how to send and receive data via bluetooth.

When you receive the text via byte array, save it to .txt file or any extension.

Your app should be installed in both devices (your device and the remote device).

There's not a way to send any data without making the user know something happens. If you send via `Intent`, a prompt will be shown on remote device (Yes/No buttons). If you install the app on remote device, user will know your app is installed on his/her device.